# Share a message with telegram within iOS app (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, share, telegram

I'm developing an iOS app with swift and I need to share a message with the telegram app when a button is pressed. I want the user to choose which contact he/she wants to share the message with.

I've tried the "tg://msg?text=" schema but it only opens telegram not the sharing page to choose a contact.

Does anyone know a way for doing this?

Thank you in advance for your help !

**Answer:**

As @Cesare pointed out the tg://msg?text=test URL had been disabled by telegram so we need a specific phone number to share the message with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram disabled the `tg://msg?text=test` URI. [You can only send direct messages to pre-chosen users or contacts](http://tsfkb.wikidot.com/tips:ios:urischeme).

So you may want to present a standard contact list and then send a message to that phone number (assuming they have Telegram).

For sure if you use a `UIActivityController` that should work.

```
@objc func didSelectShareRow() {
    let text = "Hello"
    let textShare = [text]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textShare , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know the tg://msg?text=test URL has been disabled. I think it's better for me to remove the telegram button and use a share button instead and then show UIActivityViewController.

Comment: So it is not possible to share to a specific social network? I always should open UIActivityViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use something like my [`LNExtensionExecutor`](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNExtensionExecutor), which allows you to bypass the `UIActivityViewController` and execute the standard Telegram (or any other) share extension, providing text and/or images as input items.

Comment: Great contribution, But you should mention the usage of **Private apis** clearly in your answer.

Comment: @Husam I assume it was implicitly clear this is the case, given Apple doesn’t provide any alternative to `UIActivityViewController`.